# grpc server stream terminated in client unexpectedly after grpc upgrade

Tags: python, grpc

I have a simple gRPC Python application that listens and processes a server stream messages. Basically, it looks like:

```
# creating the server RPC stream from stub
notification_stream = stub.GetNotification( filter )
try:
    for notification in notification_stream:
        #  do something with received notification
        print "Got {0}".format(notification) 
except Exception:
    print "Got exception"
    raise
print "terminated"
```

It works great with gRPC v1.7. But under v1.18, with newly generated client code, the `notification_stream` would terminate soon after receiving the first message from the server. Checking the server side (gRPC v1.18 in C++), we observed it closed the stream after the call to  `grpc::ServerReaderWriter< W, R >::Read (R *msg)` 
returned false (meaning the stream was either done, cancelled, or failed). As the result, the client received no exception (StatusCode.OK) and simply terminated. For now, we have to put the client back to v1.7 while the server is on v1.18.

I am at loss as what could be the issue given that a message was exchanged successfully on both sides. Is there a way I can get more information on what happened internally in gRPC on the client side after the first message?